# C# Web API 2 - AJAX Request para metodo PUT retornando 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, ajax

Bom dia! Estou construindo um sistema utilizando C# como back e React no front, e estou com um problema em duas controllers (supostamente), mas o erro parece ser o mesmo, sendo que sempre que faço uma requisição AJAX com o `method` do tipo `PUT`, obtenho o erro

> PUT http://localhost:49232/api/Product/1025 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Seguido por

> {Message: "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}

Li sobre CORS, fiz os ajustes recomendados em vários tópicos, mas o erro permanece. Segue o código :

```
$.ajax({
  url: URL,//A URL é montada acima, e para teste seu valor é http://localhost:49232/api/Products/1025
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: { "product": json}, //Aqui passo o objeto montado
  type: 'PUT',
  beforeSend: function () {

  },
  success: function (response) {
    // do something
  }.bind(this),
  error: function (response) {
    // do something else
  }

});
```

Action C#:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutProduct(int id, Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != product.IdProduct)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ProductExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Se puderem me ajudar, gratidão.

Comment: Adicione: [HttpPut], depois do '[ResponseType(typeof(void))]'.

Comment: @ViníciusMatos Fiz isso, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 3):

Ricardo, a sua URL está conseguindo ser resolvida? Não fiz um teste de mesa aqui mas seu exemplo usa a URL

> http://localhost:49232/api/Products/1025

E seu método está aguardando dois argumentos(um inteiro e um objeto) e tem como nome PutProduct e não Products.

Comment: Angelo, obrigado pela contribuição. A URL está sendo resolvida sim. Na verdade eu já "resolvi" o problema - Não foi uma solução de fato, mas funcionou - simplesmente excluindo a controller e recriando a mesma. Não sei o que havia de errado, mas agora funciona.

Comment: Imagina! Esse pode ser um bug de referência ou uma letra que você não estava vendo que estava errada (acontece muito comigo rs).

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu aplicativo estiver sendo hospedado no IIS, executando a API no ASP.NET Core, inclua esta linha no arquivo Web.Config

```
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
             <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```